# Prevent guessing slug

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have the following rewrite rule

```
function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array(
      'buscador-latte/(.*)/?$' =>  'index.php?page_id=866&search_parameters=$matches[1]',
    );

    $rules = $rules + $new_rules;
    return $rules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Because I need to search using the parameters passing after "buscador-latte".

The search works for URLS similar to this:

```
http://gine.desarrolloboom.com/buscador-latte/Barcelona/Badalona/Allianz/
```

But when I only type one parameter:

```
http://gine.desarrolloboom.com/buscador-latte/Barcelona/
```

It redirects to other page, not "buscador-latte".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is related to your previously written (and destroyed/vandalized) questions?

Comment: No... It's different. I don't know why is happening this and I need an answer...